# How to clear PyCharm's internal terminal text?

Tags: python, pycharm

I need to clear my PyCharm's terminal using a code and not that clear button as I want it to be automated within my program like clrscr(); in C, Also those (import os) functions don't work.All efforts appreciated

These do not work

```py
import os

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
os.system('cls')
os.system('clear')
```

You get the idea.

I expect whole run area to be cleared and not just add a few blank lines so as to appear empty.

I have made a program for playing 'Tic Tac Toe' and hence want every step to be cleared so as to appear that the "board" got updated. So the code is inside a loop and is called out multiple times.

Also there was a similar question on this site but that person didn't make it clear if he wanted it to clear screen mid-runtime

Comment: Good old *clrscr* (from *DOS* console)... Shortest (and lamest) approach: `for i in range(25): print()`

Comment: even if they did work..they all just add blank lines and you can scroll up and see all your old commands..change/check your limit of stored rows and add that many blank lines

Comment: @DerekEden doesnt the same thing happen when you `clear` in terminal? can scroll up to see

Comment: ya that's what I'm saying